# jQuery get the value from checked radio input which wasn't checked before

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung" value="Zum Einbetonieren" />
<input type="radio" name="eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung" value="Zum Einduebeln" />
```

Ater I check one of them and try to get the value with:

```
$("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked").val();
```

I get NaN, it only works when one of the the values is checked BEFORE. Are there any solutions for the js bug nr. 666?

When I simplify it with a much shorter but basically same way of reading it as the original code it works fine:

```
<input type="radio" name="eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung" value="Zum Einbetonieren" />
<input type="radio" name="eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung" value="Zum Einduebeln" />
<div style="" onclick="bla();">bla</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function bla(){
    bla = $("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked").val();
    alert(bla);
}
</script>
```

Damn I don't know what to do now :/ I also get other values from other radio inputs this way in the org code but they are prechecked so it works fine, only when I have to check them manually before clicking `bla` it's not working

[image]

```
anzahl = $("input[name=eingangstuer_anzahl]").val();
muster = $("input[name=eingangstuer_muster]:checked").val();
breite = $("input[name=eingangstuer_breite]").val();
gesamtlaengeelement = breite * anzahl / 100;
hoehe = $("input[name=eingangstuer_hoehe]").val() - $("input[name=eingangstuer_bodenfreiheit]").val();
form = $("input[name=eingangstuer_form]:checked").val();
form = form.replace('eingangstuer_form_konvex', 'Konvex').replace('eingangstuer_form_normal', 'Normal').replace('eingangstuer_form_konkav', 'Konkav');
farbe = $("input[name=eingangstuer_farbe]:checked").val();
oeffnung = $("input[name=eingangstuer_oeffnung]:checked").val();
quadratmeter = breite * hoehe;


    $.extend(true, artikel,{
        [currentid]:{"anzahl":anzahl,
        "art":"EingangstÃ¼r",
        "betriebsart": "manuel",
        "muster": muster,
        "gesamtlaengeelement": gesamtlaengeelement,
        "hoehe": hoehe,
        "form": form,
        "farbe": farbe,
        "oeffnung": oeffnung}
    });



if(form == 'Normal')
{
    if(muster == 'L3 Modern')
    {
        multiplikator = 0.35;
    }
}

if(form == 'Konkav')
{
    if(muster == 'L3 Modern')
    {
        multiplikator = 0.4;
    }
}

if(form == 'Konvex')
{
    if(muster == 'L3 Modern')
    {
        multiplikator = 0.4;
    }
}

endpreis = quadratmeter * multiplikator * anzahl;
endpreis = endpreis / 10;



if(endpreis < 350)
{
    endpreis = 350;
}


if($('input[name="eingangstuer_e_oeffner"]:checked').length > 0)
{
    $.extend(true, artikel,{
        [currentid]:{"zubehoer": "E-&Ouml;ffner"}
    });

    oeffnerpreis = 65 * anzahl;
    endpreis = endpreis + oeffnerpreis;
}





pfostenanzahl = $("input[name=eingangstuer_pfosten_anzahl]").val();
if(pfostenanzahl > 0)
{
    $('#info_pfosten_anzahl').text(pfostenanzahl);
    $('#info_pfosten_art').html('T&uuml;rpfosten');
    $('#info_pfosten_farbe').text(farbe);


    pfostenmasse = $('#eingangstuer_pfosten_masse').find(":selected").val();

    pfostenlaenge = $("input[name=eingangstuer_pfosten_laenge]").val();

    $.extend(true, artikel,{
        [currentid]:{"pfostenmasse": pfostenmasse + 'x' + pfostenlaenge}
    });

    $('#info_pfosten_masse').text(pfostenmasse + 'x' + pfostenlaenge);


    befestigung = $("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked").val();
```

So here is the whole code of the function before the needed value. As mentioned: why is it working fine when I precheck the damn `eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung`?

Comment: How do you attempt to read the value? Is it on submit, on click or something else? As it stands, neither of them is checked, so `$("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked")` is null.

Comment: What do you man how I read the value? like alert($("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked")); for instance?? "As it stands, neither of them is checked" well as I said after I check one of them I don't get any value

Comment: when do you want to get the value?
can you provide a more detailed code?

Comment: "when do you want to get the value?" what???? I'll edit the question..

Comment: @EddyUnruh What triggers reading the value? If, as you say, you check one of them and try to get the value, you must be running an event listener. What is it? Could you include more of your code?

Comment: I edited it, this sucks :/

Comment: I also get other values from other radio inputs this way but they are checked so it works fine, only when I have to check them manually it's not working

Comment: is there any errors on console? like missing jquery script or missing character like ; or closure? or syntax error?

Comment: No, no errors in console :(

Comment: This is rly nothing but a bug, f the POS who invented javascript, I'm really getting sick of it and there HAVE TO BE an alternative

Comment: *"I get NaN"* - The `.val()` method would *never* return `NaN`, though it will return `undefined` if there was no checked element - this is not a bug, it is correct behaviour. If you [edit] your question to show the actual code you are using (that is, what you do with the value returned by `.val()`) we might be able to help you further.

Comment: Look the sceenshot I posted in second edit

Comment: That's a strange result. What does `alert($("input[name=eingangstuer_pfostenbefestigung]:checked").length)` show if you put it at that same point in the code?

Comment: It shows "1" why?

Comment: If it shows 1 then that means there was one element matching the selector, and that element's value was the string `"NaN"`. I can't tell how that is happening from the minimal code shown - is there anywhere in your code where you set the value attribute of any of the checkboxes? (Or where you've accidentally called `.val()` with an argument?)

Comment: "If it shows 1 then that means there was one element matching the selector" this is a bit too much what exactly do you mean? Ok I show the whole code bevore this value is needed, I think everything after it isn't necessary? Look edit 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the god damn answer.
This function made all the trouble and wasted 5 hours of my time:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = parseInt($this.val());
        var max = parseInt($this.attr("max"));
        var min = parseInt($this.attr("min"));

        var voreinstellung = parseInt($this.data("voreinstellung"));

        if(val >= min && val <= max)
        {

        }
        else
        {
              if (val > max)
              {
                e.preventDefault();
                $this.val(max);
              }
              else if (val < min)
              {
                e.preventDefault();
                $this.val(min);
              }
        }

        if(val > 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(voreinstellung);
        }
});
```

So I chaned it to `$('input[type=number]')` f... javascript